# How to accept ALL recommended spelling correction in Microsoft word in one go?

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, microsoft-word-365

I have a **long** document which includes a lot of **repetitive** errors. Microsoft word is able to suggest appropriate correction for each of them, and I want to accept **ALL** corrections of Word. However, it is time consuming to click on each mistake one by one.

How can I accept ALL corrections in one go?

Comment: Word does not have the feature you describe at this time

Comment: If you have a number of one error, when you change that one error, there is an option to change all occurrences of that error. That should help you go much faster

Comment: I believe Ramhound is correct.  However, I also believe this is on purpose.  While Word is very good at pointing out errors and suggesting fixes, it is not infallible.  Its always best practice to look at each error and decide for yourself if the correction is appropriate in that instance.

Comment: @Keltari "Best practice" isn't always best practice in real life with its competing priorities. In many situations I would much rather let some errors get through in return for spending much, much less time. Word should have an "accept all suggestions" option.

Comment: Proposed VBA solutions at https://www.msofficeforums.com/112057-post7.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6308367/9983016.

Answer (score 0):

You could access the menu Review=>Editor, and then "Change all" for a specific error. If it's the same error everywhere, it should work for your case
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'm with Joan Eliot on this -best practice would be to separate the typing chore (which would mean having the facility to change all occurrences) from the editing job (which is of course to check your document afterwards but without having to do all that retyping in the vast majority of cases)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1169287)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).